# What's 1.5n comparison?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm beginning to learn Data Structure and Algorithms with [UCSD's MOOC](https://coursera.org/share/031c2f5b503dedac28cfe9e2eabffb7a).

For the second problem, they ask us to implement an algorithm to find the two highest values in an array.
As an additional problem, they add the following exercise:

> Exercise Break. Find two largest elements in an array in 1.5n comparisons.

I don't know exactly what 1.5 comparisons mean. I've searched on Google but couldn't find an explanation of comparisons in algorithms.

Is there a site with some examples of comparisons?

Comment: If n=10, 1.5*n=15

Comment: It's just (slightly) sloppy. It means "Find the two largest elements in an array using at most 3n/2 comparisons".

Comment: Or perhaps "find the two largest elements in an array using approximately 3n/2 comparisons."

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But I'm actually looking for some theory and application of comparisons. I mean, what does actually mean to compare something one and half time? How do I compare something half time? I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to compare something one and a half times, you have simply misunderstood.

Comment: Consider the statement "half of all people have brown hair". What does it mean for half a person to have brown hair? The answer is that it doesn't mean anything and the question is based on a misunderstanding of the original statement.

Comment: I guess I understood. Since I'm new to algorithms and thought there was some kind of technique related to if-else statements that would compare 1.5 times for every element in n.
Like, for example, you compare twice for every element of n (2n comparisons). I can imagine something being compared twice, but not 1.5 time. I got too stuck on the half.

Answer (score 0):

Is talking about the complexity of the algorithm
You have to give an algorithm who takes O(3/2 n) in the worst case.

Just to an example, bubble sort algo. takes O(n*n) in the worst case

Comment: In this case it is likely not O(1.5n), but simply 1.5n. Note that O(1.5n) = O(n).

Comment: I don't think this answer is right. This question is specifically about reducing the actual number of comparisons from the easy (approximately) 2n to something like 3n/2. I'm quite sure of this, because there's an algorithm that does this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83022/find-largest-and-second-largest-elements-of-the-array/83056#83056